# Frozen Misto pump head

Tags: oil

I bought my third Misto (love them) and the pump head does not move after filling and pressurizing the canister.  It is not clogged, as nothing has gone through it.  Is there a way to release the head for spray, or should I just dispose of it and order another?

Comment: Oddly, this came up before (http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/30580/67 ; brand new one doesn't work), but was marked as a duplicate when they never followed up with details.

Comment: Oh. Strange. Brand new, you say? I'd suggest double checking the instructions then returning it for exchange.